# Enumerate text crosses the boundaries

Tags: itemize, hyphenation, enumitem

I have simple enumeration (using enumitem package) with disabled hyphenation.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{extarticle}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=1.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, bindingoffset=1cm ]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem, showframe}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*}.]
        \item \large{\textbf{Общие положения}}
        \item \large{\textbf{Квалификационные требования}}

        \begin{enumerate}[label*={\arabic*}.]
            \item \textbf{Необходимые требования}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Опыт работы по основному направлению деятельности подразделения не менее 4 лет
            \end{itemize}
            \item \textbf{Специальные требования}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Глубокие знания и опыт организации технической поддержки
                \item Управленческая ответственность
                \item \blindtext
            \end{itemize}

        \end{enumerate}         


    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

But text crosses the frame.

[image: enumitem issue]

Why it could be? Thanks in advance.
Ivan.

Comment: Add `\usepackage{microtype}` to the preamble.

Comment: @HarishKumar thank you! I am newbie with LaTeX.